# Policy-Based Management on extended properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to use Policy-Based Management in SQL Server to enforce the usage of an extended property?  Ideally I want to setup a policy such that: a table cannot be created unless there is a matching description of the table using the extended properties of that table (MS_Description). I've looked at policy management and googled, but haven't found anything relating to extended properties.

My hope is to enforce some very basic documentation, so tables can't be created without at least a description of what the table is.

Thanks for any guidance!